# QGraphicsView scaling with High DPI

Tags: c++, qt, dpi

I have an application with QMainWindow in which I insert my own widget, inherited from QGraphicsView. As viewport I use QGLWidget. Everything works fine but with Hidh DPI there is a problem: my widget(inherited from QGraphicsView) is very small.

Before creation of QApplication I enable High DPI support by

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

and in my widget I do following (from signal that comes from QMainWindow deep in the code):

```
void MyWidget::onNeedResize(QRect newGeom)
{
      // some logic, that not interact with GUI stuff
      setGeometry(newGeom);
      setSceneRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), newGeom.size()));
      // more logic, that not interact with GUI stuff
}
```

What did I missed? Where is a problem?

**UPD1**: I **replaced QGLWidget by QOpenGLWidget** and everything started work just as expected! Without any modifications/calculations/additional stuff. Setting of the flag is enough. But the problem is I can't use QOpenGLWidget instead of QGLWidget for now.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption on why the dpi scaling does not work is because you use OpenGL widget as your viewport. From [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html):

> Applications mostly work with device independent pixels. Notable exceptions are OpenGL and code that works with raster graphics.

From that document, it means that OpenGL-content widgets will not be scaled even if you use `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling`.

Try to use `devicePixelRatio()` directly in your resizing code. An example on how it can be used within your code:

```
void MyWidget::onNeedResize(QRect newGeom)
{
      // some logic, that not interact with GUI stuff
      setGeometry(QRect(newGeom.x() * Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio(), 
                        newGeom.y() * Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio(), 
                        newGeom.width() * Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio(), 
                        newGeom.height() * Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio() ));
      setSceneRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(
                                       newGeom.width() * Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio(), 
                                       newGeom.height() * Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio() ) ));
      // more logic, that not interact with GUI stuff
}
```

That is, for every sizing/position you use within your widget, use a *scaling factor* of `Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio()`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank's a lot for trying me to help! I used your code above and now my window's area is just black. But interesting thing is when I resize window to bigger size, I can see on the bottom my QGraphicsView yanks. It's width seems ok, but it looks like QGraphicsView's y-coord == MainWindow's bottom-coord

Comment: Try to set the x and y coords to `(0,0)` when setting the geometry and see if it helps?

Comment: that is, `setGeometry(QRect(0,0, ...))`